# Corrupt data hard drive -

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

First I start by saying I am a total noob when it comes to Ubuntu and Linux OS - but I try!

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server that I use as a media and file server for many years. I switch it on and off as needed (don't leave it running). e.g. when I need to backup some photos or files off laptop (Windows). I haven't updated it in years. But lately it started playing up - I don't have details - I normally switch it on and connect to drives via windows PC. This stopped working. So I finally logged into the console and tried to update the OS. but kept getting various issues/ error messages. In the end I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 on the OS drive - not a big deal.

But now I realise that data drive (separate HDD) is also corrupt. I am unable to mount the drive. this is the last part of the error message when I try to mount:

[image: screen print of error message]

The drive is 1.7G but `sudo lsblk` says size is 3.9G

I installed `smartmontools` and ran that. Drive is SMART enabled (see diagram):

[image: Smartmon smartctl -i]

But attempting to read drive gave following error:

```
SCSI error badly formed scsi parameters
```

[image: smartctl -c screen print]

I even tried running `ddrescue` but that didn't appear to have any success as I aborted after 8 minutes and that showed no files or data as being rescued. Similar error messages to the above when mounting drive.

Sudo fdisk -l give following error (only extract provided) - buffer i/o error and DRD ERR.

[sudo fdisk -l screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AukQe.png)

Appreciate your thoughts.
Let me know if its worth taking to local IT shop or too far gone.

UPDATE
Been running ddrescue overnight (7hrs) so far 0 bytes recovered. Will let it run till the end but not feeling lucky

[ddrescue stats snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv2f7.png)

Thanks
Carlos

Comment: Hello. The drive is most likely dead and all data is lost.

Comment: Something tells me this computer is not at all maintained and the hardware is at least 15 years old ...

Comment: ddrescue can take a very long time. Many hours if the drive is big and slow.

Comment: Looks like that your drive is failing. It's gonna be hard to recover data now. Why don't you install a data recovery tool? To clone the data to a healthy drive? This might take a long time if the drive is weak but most likely will recover some of your data.

Comment: Can you clone the drive using `dd`? Might be the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

Note that hard drives *can* fail. It is hardware with a limited life span. Once broken, data from a hard drive may be very difficult to recover, even when a specialized firm is involved. This is why it is important to regularly make a backup of data anytime.

Your only option probably will be to at least replace the faulty drive.

Comment: Yes that is why it's important to backup. Or you will need to redo your assignments for work or college. Drive can fail at any moment.